# Problemas com Autenticação SMTP PHP Adobe Muse

Tags: php, html5, phpmailer

Olá, estou tentando converter o contact form do muse que utiliza a função mail() do php anônimo, e meu provedor não suporta mais esse tipo de configuração. Já procurei em diversos fóruns e tentei implementar o PHPMailer, mas por algum motivo o erro persiste.

Mensagem de Erro: 
[image: Erro]

Erro no Console:
[image: Mensagem no Console:]

Comment: Você está utilizando qual provedor? Está rodando mais coisas em PHP? Aparentemente parece que está com problema no PHP e na conexão com o seu servidor para conseguir concluir a ação. Dá uma olhada nesse tutorial para fazer um form desses na mão. é simples e está bem explicado. Somente precisa verificar se está rodando PHP já. https://www.devmedia.com.br/enviando-email-com-php/37216

Comment: Obrigado! Darei uma olhada... mas o php está funcionando sim, tem outras coisas em php que estãp rodando normal